# How to remove unwanted double quotes when converting CSV to GeoJSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv, geojson

I'm getting started with Python3 and I'm working on a script to convert a CSV file into a GeoJSON one.
The conversion works but I still have a problem with the coordinates, that are not taking the right format. I need to remove the double quotes, but it's not working.

Here is part of my code:

```
def readCsvFile():
    features=[]
    geoJson={}
    with open('resources/data_export.csv',newline= '') as csvfile:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,delimiter=',',quotechar='|')
        for row in csvReader:
            features.append({'type': 'Feature',
                            'geometry': {
                                'type': 'Point', "coordinates" : [str(row['longitude']), str(row['latitude'])]}, 'properties': {'id': decodeString(row['id']), 'field1': decodeString(row['field1']), 'field2': decodeString(row['field2'])})

    geoJson = {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': features}
    return json.dumps(geoJson)
```

I'm getting that result:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": ["16.394564", "48.246426"]}, "properties": {"id": "0", ...
```

While I'm supposed to get:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [16.394564, 48.246426]}, "properties": {"id": "0",
```

Comment: You still have two `"` in your coordinates list in your expected result, is this correct?

Comment: You do realize that `json.dumps` returns a `str` right?

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I need to remove

Comment: Try to post the first two rows or so of your `data_export.csv`

Comment: The float conversion I suggested in my answer is working for the row you provided.. (just tested it on Python 3.6) I think you might have an invalid row somewhere else

Comment: What does the `decodeString()` function do and why aren't you applying it to `row['longitude']` and `row['latitude']`? Also don't post the sample data in a comment, [edit] your question and put it there.

Answer (score 4):

Try converting it to a float instead of a string:

```
"coordinates" : [float(row['longitude']), float(row['latitude'])]}
```

Comment: I tried it and i'M GETTING THAT ERROR:  'type': 'Point', "coordinates" : [float(row['longitude']), float(row['latitude'])]},
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: `float("16.394564")` works fine for me. What is `print(row['longitude'])`?

Comment: I assume your row['longitude'] and row['latitude'] have invalid data that cannot be parsed into a float... Could you post the result of both of them as mentioned above?

Comment: HoudaF: It shouldn't matter based on the results you show in your question, but try using `float(str(row['longitude']))` and `float(str(row['latitude']))` instead. As Orphamiel said, it looks like you have some invalid data which we can't help you with unless you edit your question to include some actual sample data from the csv input file.

Comment: Perfect, It worked when I tried with only 2 lines instead of 1000 lines, there's some invalid data as you mentioned. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I've done quite a few of these in different projects. I like using pandas and rewrote a code sample you could use (if you are interested that is). Pandas will make sure your columns convert automatically to float.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests

def df2geojson(df, latlng = []):
    """Function converting pandas table to GEOJSON-format-string"""
    features = []
    for ind, row in df.iterrows():
        geometry = dict(type='Point', coordinates=row[latlng].tolist())
        properties = {k:v for k,v in row.items() if k not in latlng}
        features.append(dict(type='Feature',geometry=geometry, properties=properties))
    return dict(type="FeatureCollection",features=features)

data = '''\
id,field1,field2,longitude,latitude
0,100,100,0,16.394564,48.246426
1,200,200,0,16.494564,48.346426'''

filelikeobject = pd.compat.StringIO(data)          # simulates a file-object
df = pd.read_csv(filelikeobject)                   # should be: 'resources/data_export.csv'
jsonstr = df2geojson(df, ['latitude','longitude']) # pass dataframe and latlng colnames

#with open('output.geojson','w') as f:              # finally write to file
#    json.dump(jsonstr,f,indent=2)                  # disabled

baseurl = 'http://geojson.io/#data=data:application/json,'     # geojson.io url
url = baseurl+requests.utils.requote_uri(json.dumps(jsonstr))  # encode the json

print(url)
```

Results in an URL that you can click (use file dump if large file): http://geojson.io/#data=data:application/json,%7B%22type%22:%20%22FeatureCollection%22,%20%22features%22:%20[%7B%22type%22:%20%22Feature%22,%20%22geometry%22:%20%7B%22type%22:%20%22Point%22,%20%22coordinates%22:%20[48.246426,%2016.394564000000003]%7D,%20%22properties%22:%20%7B%22id%22:%20100.0,%20%22field1%22:%20100.0,%20%22field2%22:%200.0%7D%7D,%20%7B%22type%22:%20%22Feature%22,%20%22geometry%22:%20%7B%22type%22:%20%22Point%22,%20%22coordinates%22:%20[48.346426,%2016.494564]%7D,%20%22properties%22:%20%7B%22id%22:%20200.0,%20%22field1%22:%20200.0,%20%22field2%22:%200.0%7D%7D]%7D

[image]

Comment: thank you, It seems interesting so I will start using it.

Comment: @HoudaF If you are working with csv-files there is really no other option than pandas (today).

Comment: I'm dealing with a 10000 lines file as a start but this works only with 1000 lines, I will try Pandas, a I mentioned I'm getting started so I really need those advices. thank you

Comment: @HoudaF Also note that in this case only specify the columns for lat and lng, the other columns become properties. Pandas also let you insert a `nrows=` parameter to limit the amount of rows.

Comment: Very good, thank you so much. I will start using it immediately.